# Is there a way to catch a soap response triggered by a button click in UI

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I have a form with a huge list of parameters. Also there is a submit button in my form which calls a specific web service method on button click. I want to provide those parameters on UI rather than providing these within SOAP UI and catch the web service response generated for my request.

The reason is there are a lot of validation and its more practical to submit the request via application UI than using XML format in SOAP UI.

Is there a way to catch the soap response from back end once I hit the submit button?

Comment: are you consuming this webervice through a webform or a winform ? If you're using webforms, you would simply have to use AJAX if you want to fetch info from server directly from client-side code with no roundtrip to the server for the whole page.

Comment: This web service is basically used for web forms. But It's being used in winform as well. I'll be happy to use either one as long as I'm able to catch the response

Comment: Well, in webforms you can then use AJAX, for example. But I must admit I don't understand fully what you're up to. A webservice is never intended to be used as such, it returns data that indeed should be formatted through a proper UI anyway...

Comment: I need to write some performance tests using a certain web service. I need to catch the valid request for that web service. Easiest way to get the valid web service is to use the UI. (a lot of id's being used in fields when used SOAP UI. I can use titles instead of ids when using the form) Basically what I need to do is to get the submitted request for that web service and then use it in Jmeter as a SOAP request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you application supports HTTP Proxy you can catch requests/responses via Apache JMeter [HTTP(S) Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder). See [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for more details. Once recorded you will be able to replay requests with higher number of threads.

If not, you can always use a sniffer tool, there is a free and powerful one called [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to capture and inspect traffic.